# how to build a development version using Sphinx Read the Docs theme

Tags: python-sphinx

I was wondering how to build a development version rather than the latest version using Sphinx Read the Docs theme. Is there any place I can put like "development" indicating that it is a development version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at how we do this for [Pyramid](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/tree/master/docs). Development is on the `master` branch, and released versions are on numbered branches, e.g., `1.10-branch`.

You also need to [configure RTD to support multiple versions of your docs](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/versions.html). In Pyramid, we point `latest` at the latest released version, not the development or `master` branch.